# Awk command to powershell

Tags: powershell, awk

Hi i try to transcript an awk command to powershell

i have a text file

```
SQLBefore:=
UPDATE SYSADM.PS_S1_R_FLWUP
SET S1_FLWUP_DATE_CHK=SYSTIMESTAMP
, S1_FLWUP_DATE_LAST=NULL
WHERE S1_FLWUP_NAME='GGGGG_ETAT_JJ'

SQLAfter:=
UPDATE SYSADM.PS_S1_R_FLWUP
SET S1_FLWUP_DATE_LAST=SYSTIMESTAMP
, S1_FLWUP_STAT_SID=1
WHERE S1_FLWUP_NAME='TTTTT_ETAT_'

SQLFailed:=
UPDATE SYSADM.PS_S1_R_FLWUP
SET S1_FLWUP_DATE_LAST=S1_FLWUP_DATE_FRST
, S1_FLWUP_STAT_SID=3
WHERE S1_FLWUP_NAME='JJJJ_ETAT_JJJ'
```

And i would like to do the same than this unix command in powershell

```
cat $this_file|awk '/SQLAfter/,/SQLFailed/ {print $0}'| grep -v SQL|sed -e 's/^$//'
```

It's return

```
UPDATE SYSADM.PS_S1_R_FLWUP
SET S1_FLWUP_DATE_CHK=SYSTIMESTAMP
, S1_FLWUP_DATE_LAST=NULL
WHERE S1_FLWUP_NAME='GGGGG_ETAT_JJ'
```

I'm getting stuck to do the delimiter like awk, between "SQLBefore:=" and "SQLAfter:=" with powershell

Thanks for your help.

I'm a beginner of powershell sorry for my english

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service. Please post your attempts and highlight where you're getting stuck

Comment: Sorry I expressed myself badly I'm getting stuck to do the delimiter like awk, between "SQLBefore:=" and "SQLAfter:=" with powershell

Comment: But what is the expected output? Try to provide a simplified example that goes to the ultimate goal, skipping the details that may confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility, assuming I'm reading the question correctly (however "bad" you think your English might be I assure you it's considerably better than my AWK).

```
((get-content testfile.txt -raw) -split 'SQL(?:Before|After):=')[1]
```

Comment: Thx a lot it's works great

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mjolinor Thx a lot it's works great its this who search between the chain of character **(?:Before|After)**?  It s regex?

Comment: Yes, that is regex. Actually the entire argument 'SQL(?:Before|After):=' is a regex.

Comment: I need to improve my knowledge thank you for your reactivity and your perfect english :)